# Why is this input an invalid format for Joda-Time PeriodFormatter?

Tags: java, string, jodatime, jodconverter

I am trying to convert strings like `1h 30m 5s` or `5m` or `38s` or `1h 3s` into an integer value representing total time in seconds. So for example, `1m 20s` would result in an integer value of 80 for 80 seconds.

I am using Joda Time:

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .appendDays().appendSuffix("d").appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter(" ")
        .appendHours().appendSuffix("h").appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter(" ")
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("m").appendSeparatorIfFieldsAfter(" ")
        .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("s")
        .toFormatter();

int time = formatter.parsePeriod("30s").getSeconds(); //Throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Throws an IllegalArgumentException with practically every string i pass in, saying "Invalid format".

I don't understand why this wouldn't be working. I can't pass ANYTHING into this without getting an illegalArgumentException. Does anybody have any guidance on how to tweak my formatter settings to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode. It’s creator went on to lead JSR 310 which brought the *java.time* classes now built into Java 8 and later.

The ISO 8601 standard [format for a span of time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) unattached to the timeline is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where the `P` marks the beginning, and the `T` separates the two portions.

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 standard formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

So I would solve your problem with simple text manipulation. Delete your SPACE characters. Change to uppercase.

```
java.time.Duration.parse( "PT" + "1h 30m 5s".replace( " " , "" ).toUpperCase() )
```